# Export LDAP entries from 389 Directory Server?

Tags: ldap, export

Can someone tell me the best way to export entries (user information, their groups and roles, etc) from 389 Directory Server so it can be best imported into a different LDAP server?  Do these files follow some standard format?  Is there a general best practice to doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is very easy from the 389-console (the UI for 389 Directory server).

From the 'Tasks' tab on the UI for the directory server, click on the 'Export Databases' link.

This will export the LDAP schema as and LDIF (LDAP Data Interchange Format) file, which is a standardized format for LDAP information.

Answer (score 1):

With the command line below you can export to LDIF format, that you can then import into another server:

```
db2ldif -s 'dc=example,dc=com' -a /tmp/ldifdump.ldif  -m -E -q
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.